# ADB Manager Nexus 4 issues

Tags: java, android, adb, monitor, nexus-4

I have some issues to connect my Nexus 4 and use the debug usb. (Unlike my samsung galaxy tab which is working perfectly)

First of all I've done this :
1. Activate Usb debugging on my phone
2. Allow Unknown Resources

But when I connect my phone, ADB monitor don't show any device, so I've tried this :

1. Uninstalled the driver from Device Manager
2. Let it automatically install the generic 'MTP device driver'
3. Right clicked on the new device and selected 'Update Driver'
4. Selected 'Have Disk' and pointed it to [android-sdk-dir]\extras\google
5. Watched an 'ADB' driver install.

But even so my phone is still not shown on Android Debug Monitor...

I don't know what to do :( thanks for your help !

edit : My PC is a windows 8 and I use Android Studio to develop my apps

Comment: And you device is a Mac/PC/Linux?

Comment: While it cannot be listed in your debug monitor, can you list it with adb devices in command line?

Comment: yes but it's not working either =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

1. Go into device manager.
2. Android device > Google nexus 4 ADB interface.
3. Driver > Uninstall. (Make sure to check "delete the driver software for this device").
4. Uninstall then take out usb and put it back again. It should work now.

I've always found setting up device debugging to be very temperamental.

Failing that:

In the past what worked for me was downloading the USB drivers.

You can find a list of devices and support from here
http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

And sepecifically the nexus USB drivers here
http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

Comment: I retried with this driver but still not working..
But thanks ;)

Comment: yeah it finally works ! But I've tried this before and that didn't work, I don't why this time it's working ^^
But thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the drivers using this program

http://adbdriver.com/downloads/